# Display locale currency symbol using ICU C API?

Tags: c, locale, currency, icu

I need to know how to use the ICU4C version 52 C API to display the locale Currency Symbol and code. i.e. ($ - USD)

Comment: Actually I'm not a C expert. I have a made program using ICU4J to display all locales info. Currency/ date and time format / yes and no strings ...etc. I need to something similar with the C API.

Comment: I have the ICU source code and built its tests but can not find the correct method to use.

Comment: Have you tried looking at [the documentation](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/)?

Comment: yeah sure . I searched it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably more than one way how to do this. Here is one, that I think should work (untested):

[Get the number format](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/unum_8h.html#a581f9eb53d6b1b052b751272e1c6b67f) and [format the value using it](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/unum_8h.html#a8cbd385fd0b01975ad6a0742c6e5c512):

```c
 UErrorCode success = U_ZERO_ERROR;
 UNumberFormat *nf;
 const char* myLocale = "fr_FR";

 // get locale specific number format
 nf = unum_open( UNUM_CURRENCY, myLocale, success );

 // use it to format the value
 UChar buf[100];
 unum_formatDouble  (nf, 10.0, buf, 100, NULL, &success);   

 // close the format handle
 unum_close(nf);
```

Comment: How to print the currency code and symbol itself without formatting a number ?

Comment: @AyaR.: You can get the currency ISO code from the locale using [`unum_getTextAttribute`](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/unum_8h.html#a497b8a591fbac7c2d2e604f06a403be1) with [`UNUM_CURRENCY_CODE`](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/unum_8h.html#a9d3fc41af40c7a4437230943eb265725). I do not see a way to get the national symbol without actually formatting the number.

Answer (score 1):

Or, more directly, use `ucurr_getName()` with the `UCURR_SYMBOL_NAME` selector. You can also use `ucurr_forLocale()` or `ucurr_forLocaleAndDate()` to get the currency code without needing a formatter. Note that there can be multiple currencies for a locale.